# RubyMotion with BubbleWrap

Tags: rubymotion

I'm just starting to play around with Ruby Motion (v 1.9) and I'm having some trouble including BubbleWrap (v 0.2.1) into my project.

My Rakefile looks like:

```
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project'
require 'rubygems'
require 'bubble-wrap'

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
  app.name = "Hello"
  app.device_family = :ipad #[:ipad,:iphone]

  app.files += Dir.glob(File.join(app.project_dir, 'vendor/BubbleWrap/lib/**/*.rb'))
end
```

I've also tried by just using

require 'bubble-wrap'

but I consistently get an error that looks like this:

```
ERROR! Can't resolve dependency `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap
0.2.1/lib/pollute.rb' because ./Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/pollute.rb 
is not in ["./app/app_delegate.rb", 
"./app/login_controller.rb", "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/app.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/gestures.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/http.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/json.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/kernel.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/ns_index_path.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/ns_notification_center.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/ns_user_defaults.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/ui_button.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/ui_view_controller.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap/version.rb", 
"/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/pollute.rb"]
```

Do the newer versions of RubyMotion not work with BubbleWrap?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I'm using Bubblewrap 0.2.1 with Rubymotion 1.9 in tandem with Ruby 1.9.3p125 (via RVM) successfully. Maybe it has something to do with using the OSX 1.8 system Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This was fixed as of bubble-wrap 0.3.1

This is a bug in the `bubble-wrap` gem, it's trying to prepend the gem's path with a `./`. I opened a [pull request](https://github.com/mattetti/BubbleWrap/pull/43).

For now, you can either use something like RVM or rbenv to install a separate copy of Ruby and use that, or you can manually patch `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bubble-wrap-0.2.1/lib/bubble-wrap.rb` by changing line 14 to this:

```
path = /^\.|\/Users\/|\/Library\/Ruby\/Gems\//.match(x) ? x : File.join('.', x)
```